# Optional datasources in java web applications

Tags: java, websphere, datasource, web.xml

I'm creating a java web application which should run on multiple application servers (jetty, tomcat, websphere, jboss). There is an optional datasource in this application. If it is configured the application will use it, otherwise some functionality in the application will be disabled.

The problem is, if I define the resource-ref in the web.xml, it will be required to be defined in the application context. If I don't define it in the web.xml, then when I try to deploy the application in websphere, there is no way to reference the datasource in the application.

Is there a way to make websphere aware of the optional datasource without always having to define it in the application context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an "optional data source".  Instead, always define the resource-ref, and add an env-entry:

```
@Resource(name="useDataSource")
private boolean useDataSource;
```

...or corresponding XML:

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>useDataSource</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.Boolean</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>false</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

The value of the env-entry can be changed at deployment time.

Comment: AFAICS the problem stated by the OP is that if you add the `<resource-ref>` you are still forced to provide a matching data source in the application server, which might be not needed

Comment: WebSphere allows you to specify a binding to a resource that does not exist.  So, for the scenario where OP doesn't need a data source, he can provide a "dummy" binding.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to define a dummy datasource, since it makes deploying unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @timotep You don't have to define a dummy data source, you would reference a non-existent data source.  I don't know of a more convenient solution, sorry.